# asp.net application takes long to start--even after compiling

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have an asp.net app on IIS 7.  It is 'pre-compiled', but I understand that IIS must still compile the assemblies the first time they're run.

Here is the problem--After I publish and deploy the application, I log in, and (as expected) it takes about 30 seconds to see the login page.  Then I visit every page so that they are compiled (I have used the 'individual file for each page' or whatever option).

So far so good.

Then 10 minutes later i log in and it's near instantaneous.   Still good and expected.

Yet the next day, my first logon takes 30 seconds or more again.  Nobody changed web.config or copied any new assemblies in the meantime--this I am sure of.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?  Is there an application timeout (as opposed to a session timeout)?   Is there some setting in IIS admin console that I may have left at some default that is not optimal?
Thanks for any help on this,
James

Comment: IIS recycles an application after 20 minutes of no activity by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, starting an ASP.NET application in IIS is relatively slow. How much? It depends...

It's slow again the next day because IIS shuts down apps when they are inactive for some time.

The solution is "Application Initialization". This is built-in in IIS 8 and available out-of-band as a module for IIS 7.5:
http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization

Comment: Thanks very much, I'm glad it wasn't some obscure or arcane setting that I was forgetting to adjust.  Guess I'm stuck though, since I'm at IIS 7.  Maybe a batch script that calls the login page at 7am before people arrive is a workaround...

Comment: Yes, pinging the application is a (dirty) work-around. You can also try to optimize your startup time, I think 30 seconds is a bit long. The 'web application' project type is much better in this regard than the 'web site' because everything is compiled into one dll ahead of time (something I think you can achieve with web sites as well, using some pre-compilation options).

Answer (score 0):

There is an Idle Time-Out on the Application Pool under Advanced Settings. Set this to 0 and the application will not stop due to inactivity.